# How to write a subquery in Django ORM where the subquery returns the filter field value

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

I want to query such that i get all the samples having same sample type and the sample type can be defined using the latest sample registered.

I tried my best and come up with two queries but could not figure out how to make it a single query.

```
q=Sample.objects.filter(submitted_by_id=self.request.user.id).latest('registration_time') 

queryset = Sample.objects.filter(sample_type = q.sample_type)
```

Is it possible to club these queries or do i need to use a raw query.

EDIT:
I am using these queries in get_queryset method.If i execute both these queries alone, they give the expected output. When when i add them in get_queryset method which returns the queryset gives me error : 
DoesNotExist: Sample matching query does not exist.
What am i doing wrong???

EDIT:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/samples/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 57, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 87, in view
 return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 40, in list
queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
File "/home/tudip/Desktop/Raw_Desktop/ubiota/personalbiota_unmrged_with_rest_api/personalbiota/samples/views.py", line 576, in get_queryset
q=     Sample.objects.filter(submitted_by_id=self.request.user.id).latest('registration_time')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 502, in latest
return self._earliest_or_latest(field_name=field_name, direction="-")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 496, in _earliest_or_latest
return obj.get()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 357, in get
self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: Sample matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Your code is already pretty clear. There's no point to do it in one query and I don't think there's any performance concern with this.

Comment: please see the edit.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full traceback.

Comment: The error message is telling you that the current user has not submitted any Samples.

Comment: what could be the best solution in this kind of scenario. should i go for try catch.?